# Correctly setting JAVA_HOME path to copy file and save locally in XP

Tags: environment-variables, command-prompt, java-home

This might be a simple problem, but I'm trying to set my java_home environmental variable to my JDK directory, so I can run a command in the command prompt to copy a WSDL file and save it locally. I currently have my JAVA_HOME path set as my JDK installation directory, but when I run the command in the command prompt I'm still getting the error

```
Please first set JAVA_HOME environment variable, it's jdk installation directoy
```

I've tried closing the console, retyping the java_home path, and trying again but the error remains. I've restarted my machine after setting the path but no luck. I've looked at other posts and can't see any information that has worked so far. I'm running XP. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What do you see when you echo the value of JAVA_HOME, e.g. `echo %JAVA_HOME%` ?

Comment: @atkretsch I get the path 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin\javac.exe', which is what my JAVA_HOME path is currently set to

Comment: Try setting JAVA_HOME to just `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\`.  JAVA_HOME isn't meant to be the path to the compiler, but to the entire JDK/JRE (i.e. it should be a directory, not a file).

Comment: @atkretsch thanks for the suggestion but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it didn't like the spaces in the path, so I replaced 'Program Files' with 'Progra~1', so the full path read

`C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_07`

Answer (score 0):

Add JAVA_HOME to System Variables.

These instructions might be *slightly* off, I haven't been on XP in a while.

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Right click "My Computer"
3. Select "Properties"
4. Go to "Advanced" tab.
5. Click Environment Variables
6. Click "New... (or find the existing JAVA_HOME)
7. Set your JAVA_HOME

NOTE: You can also get to the System Properties through Control Panel

Comment: the current JAVA_HOME I'm working on (the one giving me the error) is one I added in earlier, there wasn't a pre-existant JAVA_HOME there